# Moving logout button to be easier to find

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

I was just wondering if we can move the logout button from the Stack Exchange drop down menu to an `onHover:active` dropdown in the sticky bar. It's kind of hard for some new users to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a hover event would make accidentally opening the panels on the top bar a more common occurrence. Furthermore, I fail to see how that would make the logout link easier to find either. The user would still have to hover over the required area.

Changing from a click to a hover wouldn't help users find it accidentally since when a panel opens through hover, no-one's going to spend the time to read it but rather be annoyed by the intrusion.

The log out link is not the hardest thing to find. Before reading your question body I tried to find the link by myself (having never logged out of Stack Exchange) and the Stack Exchange button was the first place I tried. I'm not sure how much of a problem finding the button is anyway, but regardless this isn't the right solution.